# Issues with start url when setting up salesforce as IdP for Office365

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, office-365

I have been trying to setup Salesforce as Identity Provider for Office 365 apps as per the [**article**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=identity_provider_examples_office365.htm) using SAML.

I have setup start url as https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?msg=AuthnReq&realm=my-user-domain-here.my.salesforce.com&wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline&wctx=bk%3D1367916313%26LoginOptions%3D3.

Note that I have replaced *PostToIDP.srf* from the url in article with *login.srf* as it was giving not found error.

When I launch Office365 app through salesforce app laucher, it navigates to office but shows following error: AADSTS70001: Application with identifier https://urn-federation-MicrosoftOnline was not found in the orgId tenant.

Is there anything that I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the **urn:federation:** from the url, I can see a good redirect. Can you try with start url as https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf?msg=AuthnReq&realm=my-user-domain-here.my.salesforce.com&wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=MicrosoftOnline&wctx=bk%3D1367916313%26LoginOptions%3D3